# Accessing an instance variable in main() method?

Tags: java, static, instance

```
 class Test {
     Test obj;
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         obj = new Test();
     }
 }
```

I am aware of the fact that instance variable and non-static methods are not accessible in a static method as static method don't know about anything on heap.

i want to ask if main is a static method how can i access an instance variable 'obj'.

Comment: Define it's as static.

Comment: You answered your own question; you have to declare it as `static`

Comment: If you want to access a non-static member from a static context you need to create an instance of the class containing the non-static member first. The instance gives you the non-static context that you need in order to access the non-static members of that instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why accessing an instance variable in static `main` is impossible: **Instance variable of *which instance* would you expect to access?**

A possible misconception is that Java creates an instance of your main class when the application is started - that is not true. Java creates no such instance, you start in a static method, and it is up to you what instances of which classes you create.

---

Ways out of this:

- Declare `Test obj` as `static`

  ```
  static Test obj;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      obj = new Test();
  }
  ```
- Declare `Test obj` as local variable inside main

  ```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      Test obj = new Test();
  }
  ```
- Create an instance of `Test` in your `main`, then you'll be able to access its instance variables

  ```
  static Test obj;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      obj = new Test();
      obj.myInstanceVariable = ... // access of instance variable
  }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, If I create an object of the class inside the main() method then I can access instance variable because instance variable are allocated within object. Is this the reason why we can access the instance variable inside a static method without declaring them as static?

Comment: Yes. There§s no absolute rule that "you may not access any instance variable in a static method". The only rule is that to access an instance variable, you first need an instance whose instance variable you wish to access. Static methods are not associated with any instance, so you cannot just write `myInstanceVar` and hope to access *some* instance's variable. If you have an instance, you are free to access its instance variables.

Answer (score 2):

Cannot access non-static variables inside a static method. So make obj as a static variable

```
static Test obj;
public static void main(String[] args) {
   obj = new Test();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`obj` Should be `static` like this:

```
   static Test obj;
```

The main method does not have access to non-static members either.